# How to connect to sql server from php (other computer)

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a computer install `sql server 2005`
And other computer install `xampp v3.2.1`

i try to connect to sql server 2005 by php in computer install xampp but not working.

**In computer install xampp i do:**

i download driver 3.0 for php from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

and i copy 2 file `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` to `Xampp\php\ext`

and i add code below to php.ini

```
[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems=-1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity=-1
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors=0
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

i test connection by

```
$serverName = "nameserver";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"namedatabase");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "success";
}else {
    die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
```

but i get error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

How to connect to sql server from php. Thanks

Comment: i dont know if thats the right way to go, but I believe you are better off using a ODBC setting. Have a quick glimpse here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp . It sums down to setting up a ODBC source on your xampp running machine and using `$conn=odbc_connect();` instead of sqlsrv_connect

Comment: Install a database tool first, and check whether you can operate on the remote database. SQL Squirrel can MS SQL Server 2005. (Need Java runtime though.)

Comment: @JoopEggen but if i using any `serverName` then i still get similar error :(?

Comment: I was wondering whether you can access the database on the other computer. That would be the first check. And having a database tool always comes handy. I never combined MSSQL with PHP, so better search for yourself what the URI of the server name must be. You could also try to access the remote database with MSWord; for instance a dummy mailing list. Sorry, if you already have access to the database server.

Comment: @JoopEggen I just install SQLserver 2008 on same computer install xampp. But i still get same error? The error maybe say it work with sqlserver 2012?

Comment: Sorry for the effort. I cannot authoratively state it, but you seem to be doing everything right; `PWD=>'...', UID=>'...'` should not be supported. Consider Najzero's ODBC maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error message where it says "This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client." The client is an extra piece of software you install and you can get installer you download from Microsoft.

I'm not sure if this will work on SQL Server 2005 though?